# Parametrize a Pytest using a dictionary with key/value individual pairs mapping

Tags: pytest

Have multiple tests in one test class. I would like to use a dictionary to parametrize the class.

Dictionary structure: `{key1: [val_1, val2], key2: [val_3, val4]}`

Test:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('key, value', [(k, v) for k, l in some_dict.items() for v in l], scope='class')  
# ^^^ the best solution that I've found but still not as expected, and without IDS ^^^
class TestSomething:
    def test_foo(self):
        assert True
    def test_boo(self):
        assert True
```

Expected order (`ids` including, both key and values are objects and can provide '.name' property):

```
<Class TestSomething>
  <Function test_foo[key1_name-val1_name]>
  <Function test_boo[key1_name-val1_name]>
  <Function test_foo[key1_name-val2_name]>
  <Function test_boo[key1_name-val2_name]>
  <Function test_foo[key2_name-val3_name]>
  <Function test_boo[key2_name-val3_name]>
  <Function test_foo[key2_name-val4_name]>
  <Function test_boo[key2_name-val4_name]>
```

How can I add `ids` for this parametrize?

Comment: Have to tried to add an respective `ids` argument, e.g. something like `ids=lambda v: v.name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a call to an external function in charge of formatting names from parameters value.

```py
def idfn(val):
    # receive here each val
    # so you can return a custom property
    return val.name


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "key, value",
    [(k, v) for k, l in some_dict.items() for v in l],
    scope="class",
    ids=idfn,
)
class TestSomething:
    def test_foo(self, key, value):
        assert True
```

But the simple solution with a lambda suggested by MrBean also works. In your simple case I would pick this one and use the external function only when more complex formatting is required.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "key, value",
    [(k, v) for k, l in some_dict.items() for v in l],
    scope="class",
    ids=lambda val: val.name,
)
class TestSomething:
    def test_foo(self, key, value):
        assert True
```

The available options are presented in the [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids)

Answer (score 1):

There is another (better) way to do this if you want many to many mappings.
You just simply use two decorators together. It would probably not fully fit your case as you want to have a dict, but I think it's worth mentioning this way of doing it as well in case you decide to refactor your code in future.

For example -

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [4, 5, 6])
def test_function(x, y):
    assert x + y > 5
```

The test function will be run with the following parameter combinations:

```
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(3, 6)
```